# Adding data column by column in postgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, database, table

I organize my data in different txt files and dat. files, mostly in each file there is one specific column of data. Now I want to import and combine 4 of them to create a table. Say I have one file for feature ID, one for timestamp, one for the WKT coordinates, and one for the feature's length. I want to create a table joining four of them like

feature_ID | timestamp | WKT | length

I also have to combine 5 files into one to complete the data for some column since the amount of data is too large (e.g. the first file contains 1-100000 data points, the 2nd one is from 100001 to 200000 etc.) Can I do this simply by importing these files to the table in the correct order?

Comment: As it stands, this is not really a GIS question.  I'd  recommend you make it GIS-relevant by using a "geom" column of GEOMETRY type in lieu of a "wkt" column of VARCHAR or CLOB.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some pieces missing in your question; it may be helpful to be more precise.

Right now, if you have 4 files of data with one column in each, how do you know they match each other? What is the (primary) key to each of these? You could create a new table based on joins between existing tables. Also you have a column for coordinates as well as length -- is your feature type a point or a line?

Also, you may not be maximizing the power of PostGres without the extension of POSTGIS being enabled, which allows for spatial extensions and features -- could be more powerful to add a vertex based on points/coordinates for future analysis, for example. (Depends on what your'e going to do.)